# Another proof (check) that the set of isolated points of a set in $\mathbb R^n$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Just thinking if this proof works, and i have some "not so explicit" ending so i would love if you suggest a way for refining this.

> ***Theorem*** : $S \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a set. Then the set of isolated points of $S$ is countable.

Proof: Let $S_{\lambda}$ denote the set of isolated points of $S$.

Thus $\forall ~ \bf{x}$ $ \in S_{\lambda}$, $\exists ~ \varepsilon_{\bf{x}} \in \mathbb R^+$ such that $B(\bf{x}$ ,$~\varepsilon_{\bf{x}})\cap S =\phi$

We know that the set of open balls of rational coordinates is countable.

Say $\bf{x}$ $=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ and chooae rationals $r_j$ such that $||x_j -r_j||<\frac{\varepsilon_{\bf{x}}}{4n}$.

Set $r_{\phi_x}=(r_1,r_2,\dots, r_n)$

Then $||~ \bf{x}$ $-r_{\phi_x}~||< \frac{\varepsilon_{\bf{x}}}{4}$

Thus $B(r_{\phi_x,\frac{\varepsilon_{\bf{x}}}{4}}) \subseteq B(\bf{x}$ $,\varepsilon_{\bf{x}})$.
Like this we can generate a ball with rational coordinate which is a subset of the ball with center at $\bf{x}$ with radius $\varepsilon_{\bf{x}}$ for all $x \in S_{\lambda}$.

To end, we define the map $\Gamma:B_{\mathbb Q}\to B_{S_{\lambda}}$ (where $B_{\mathbb Q}$ is the set kf balls with rational coordinates (and is countable) and $B_{S_{\lambda}}$ is the set of balls $B(\bf{y}$ $,\varepsilon_{\bf{y}})$ for all $\bf{y}$ in $S_{\lambda}$) such that $\Gamma (B(r_{\phi_x},\frac{\varepsilon_{\bf{x}}}{4}))=B(\bf{x}$ $,\varepsilon)$.

This map is injective when the $r_{\phi_y}$'s are kept fixed and hence $B_{S_{\lambda}}$ is countable which gives (please suggest a good way, i mean intuitively it makes me think its correct but, here i am in need of much help) $S_{\lambda}$

Much thanks!

Comment: There are a few typographical errors that I can see how to fix, but it's not clear what is meant by "$||x_j -r_j||$".

Comment: The euclidean norm..

Comment: And oh, $j$ ranges from 1 to n

Comment: Then you should write "$\|\mathbf{x} - r_{\phi_x}\|.$" But the notation "$r_{\phi_x}$" is a strange one, in more than one way. Leaving aside the inconsistent use of typefaces, what does the subexpression "$\phi_x$" mean?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley i actually wanted to emphasize that it depends on the choice of $x$ so wrote it. And i love phi, lambda, gamma so use it whenever suitable :D

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Please see the answer to that question now, I've edited to include the correct answer. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Around each isolated point $x ∈ S$ is an open $n-ball$ $B(x)$ such that $B(x)\cap S=\phi$.Then there is an $n-ball$ $A_x$ with rational radius and rational center coordinates such that $x ∈ A_x ⊂ B(x)$. The map $x\longmapsto A_x$ is a one-to-one correspondence between the isolated points of
$S$ and a subset of the countable set of all open $n-balls$ with rational center and radius.

Comment: Sorry, but this is exactly the same as what is written in a solution manual to apostol's analysis. And i am interested in understanding errors in my approach as that helps me a lot better to learn

Comment: Ok.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyways! I appreciate it :)

Comment: Thanks. Well ,it is very good to solve problems in a great way as you want to do.

Comment: Yeah, as i self study most things in math so that plays a major role.